# How to invoke a function in java file from a java file

Tags: java

I have two java files named `Admin.java` and `Search.java` in the same folder. I need to call the Search `doGet` Method. How do I do it?

I need to invoke

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
```

present in the `Search.java` file.

Comment: `doGet` in a Servlet is normally called by the application server rather than your own code (unless maybe if you are writing tests, or possibly passing on a call in from another servlet :/); are you sure you want to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the Search-ctor, and whether you have request/response objects already.

```
Search search = new Search (/*...*/);
search.doGet (request, response);
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically spoken,

1. create an instance of `Search`
2. call the `doGet()` method on that instance

But we usually don't call `doGet` directly, so I'm strongy in doubt, if that's what you really want...

```
// in some method in Admin.java

Search search = new Search();
try {
   search.doGet(someRequest, someResponse);
} catch (ServletException e) {
   // TODO handle exception
} catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO handle exception
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your Search.java looks like a `Servlet`, you'd have to invoke it by hitting a URL mapped to this Servlet. See more [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/servlet/index.html)